# Unit test to check for global authorization filter on action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm writing unit tests using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` and Moq for an ASP.NET MVC 5 app that has a custom authorization filter added via `FilterConfig.cs`:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeRedirect());
        //...
    }
}
```

Here's the custom authorization attribute:

```
public class AuthorizeRedirect: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                action = "Redirect",
                controller = "Error"
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a slightly modified version of the `IsAnonymous` method from here: https://datatellblog.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/unit-testing-asp-net-mvc-authorization/. However it only checks the method/controller for explicitly defined `[AuthorizeRedirect]` attribute; in its absence, it considers the action to be anonymous.

Is it possible to detect that the above attribute has been applied globally in a unit test when checking if an action is allowing anonymous access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to test for it: see if it's added to the global filters,

```
// Arrange
var coll = new GlobalFilterCollection();

// Act
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(coll);
var authorized = coll.Any(x => x.Instance is AuthorizeRedirect);

// Assert
Assert.IsTrue(authorized);
```